# How can I print to a Lexmark X3550 printer using Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cups, printer

I have a Lexmark X3550 printer and a computer running Ubuntu. Is there any hope in being able to print to this particular printer using Ubuntu? I am not familiar with CUPS. Is this an option?

Comment: If you ever want to replace your "paperweight" with a printer that supports linux/unix, you can search the [printer database](http://www.openprinting.org/printers) at OpenPrinting.org for information about how well printers are supported.

Answer (score 1):

There are bad news for you, Lexmark driver for linux are absent and seems there isn't support for this printer in CUPS ...

Sorry but there's few chance to print with Lexmark X3550 from ubuntu or another linux OS for the moment ...