# Ubuntu Lexmark X4580 Driver?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, printer

[How can I print to a Lexmark X3550 printer using Ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/questions/175678/how-can-i-print-to-a-lexmark-x3550-printer-using-ubuntu)

Sorry for the redundancy, but I was just wanting to make sure that the Lexmark X4580 (part of the 3500-4500 series) also is not Linux compatible, such as the X3550 in the linked question above?

I am running Ubuntu 10.04

Thanks, Amy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is bad news for you. Only very few linux drivers are available for Lexmark printers. Whether or not a particular model will work is completely hit and miss. If I were you, I would start looking for a different printer. Brother have excellent linux support for their printers, and so do HP.